# Compare the date from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Sever 2005

Table1

```
ID StartDate EndDate

001 02/23/2010 07/22/2010
002 05/03/2010 null
003 02/02/2011 null
...
```

Table2

Date

```
02/24/2011
02/25/2011
...
...
```

Condition

- If the `enddate` is not null then `startDate` compare with max(date) from table2, if the startdate > 6 month then it should display as "Expired"

How to make a query for the above condition.

Need query Help.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Please attempt the question with CASE WHEN, etc. It does not look difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select 
  StartDate,
  [Status]=Case  
        when DATEDIFF(m,StartDate,(Select MAX(Date) from Table2))>6
        then 'Expired' 
        Else 'Valid'
        end

  From Table1
  where EndDate is not null
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Case
        When EndDate Is Not Null Then EndDate
        When Table1.StartDate > DateAdd(mm, 6, T2.MaxDate) Then 'Expired'
        End
From Table1
    Cross Join  (
                Select Max( [Date] ) As MaxDate
                From Table2
                ) As T2
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is incomplete

1. If the enddate is not null then startDate compare with max(date) from table2

   - how to compare? greater than? less than? equal to?
2. if the startdate > 6 month then it should display as "Expired"

But let's assume you mean

1. If the enddate is not null then startDate compare with max(date) from table2

   - ***it is expired if `enddate < max(date)`***
2. ***otherwise*** if the startdate ***is older than*** 6 month then it should display as "Expired"

Then the query becomes

```
select
  case when EndDate < MaxDate then 'Expired'
       when EndDate is null and StartDate < DateAdd(m,-6,GetDate()) then 'Expired'
       else 'OK'
  end
from Table1 T1
cross join (select max(date) MaxDate from Table2) T2
```